# Download Zip Files using Wildcards

Tags: java, automation

I have the quite challenge. the challenge is download the zip files from particular link and the link will change every day, please find the below examples.

1) https://www.ccilindia.com/Statistics/Lists/DailyDataForInfoVendors/Attachments/2172/DFIV_23_03_2018.zip

2)https://www.ccilindia.com/Statistics/Lists/DailyDataForInfoVendors/Attachments/2171/DFIV_22_03_2018.zip

**Is it possible to download zip files with the help of wildcard character (*) ?** like below example

https://www.ccilindia.com/Statistics/Lists/DailyDataForInfoVendors/Attachments/(variable)/DFIV*.zip

Note that 2171 and 2172 belongs to particular dates number.. so number also will change every day for that we can use **(variable)**. i have to download zip from 1000 to 2172.

Comment: @ashleedawg. is it possible do in VBA ?

Comment: Establish the mapping between the date and the suffix number and include it in your requested URL. If you need just the "latest", ask the team publishing the file to name the file "latest.zip" and archive older entries. Another option will be to ask them to publish a listing of all the files in the directory, parse it in your application and construct the URL basing on your arbitrary logic. Not a programming question.

Comment: @kryger... the issue is that website having only one link to download latest zip file. i have the java code to download that file but i want to download zip files from Jan 18 ....Is it possible to download the files by using of Wildcard Character?

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is an ftp protocol available?

Comment: *"Is it possible to download the files by using of Wildcard Character"* No. There's no such thing in the HTTP protocol. Even if you wanted to go down the "brute force" path, if you have no listing of files on the remote server "`*`" would effectively match an infinite amount of strings.